# Determine max, min of width, height device media query css3 by yourself?

Tags: html, css

Assum that I have a device has size 1024X768, I want to use media query css 3 to hide or show (example) some elements. How I know what size is max-width, min-width, ... etc? Thanks for watching :)

Comment: I think this is just possible with javascript. the jQuery way would be: $( window ).height(); https://api.jquery.com/height/ and $( window ).width();  https://api.jquery.com/width/

Comment: I know that. Example, with screen 1024x768, what size is min-width, max-width, min-height, max-height?

Comment: Well I'm not real sure what you want!? min- and max-, with and height are css rules you can use them on every element. Could you please update your question and be more clear what you want? Maybe provide a fiddle with the problem and explain the expected result..

Answer (score 0):

Can you please elaborate your question a little bit more. What do you actually want? You want to find out the min width and height of the device or you know these values and you just want to apply media queries to hide/show elements?

follow:- http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/ and try to go through the comments also may be this can help you out.

and http://nmsdvid.com/snippets/ for deciding device widths.